# A confusion on baisc conditional statement. Logical falsehood entails everything as long as antecedent is not universally true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

In the logic, we could assign T\F to antecedent and consequent to evaluate the conditional statement. It's easy to evaluate because it's either universally true or false.

**example 1**. If $4$ is an even number, then there is an infinite number of integers.

$4$ is an even number, universally true

there is an infinite number of integers, universally true.

Therefore this statement is T

**Q1** What if antecedent and consequent are contingent. How should I verify the statement T or F

**example 2** If tomorrow rain heavily, then the streets will be empty.

When I have not learned logic, I would say this is false. I would say

"Oh, if raining tomorrow, it's not necessarily will have no people on the street"

**But now, I may say "well, tomorrow may not be raining", logical falsehood entails everything.**

**Q2** what kind of arguing I got here?  I felt something go wrong when dealing with a conditional statement.

When I deeply think about those, I am quite confusing. Especially when dealing with some (not logic) exam questions , like verifying the statement "If $A$ then $B$", as long as $A$ is not universally true, I always would like to claim this statement is true by logical falsehood entails everything, but this is certainly not the correct answer.

**example 3** If $X$ is greater than $4$, then $X$ is divisible by $2$. (False, e.g. $7$)

**Q3 When one is claiming $X$ is not necessarily divisible by 2 when X is greater than 4.  what kind of basic logic embedding in this reasoning?**

I know that in the proof, one needs to find $(p\land\neg q)$ implies a contradiction to disproof the statement, but for this specific statement, I don't see a contradiction, only the existence of (p &~q) I could also argue that X is not always greater than 4, logical falsehood entails everything.

**Q4** What is the contradiction in this example, and how should I convinced myself do not use logical falsehood entails everything for verifying conditional statement when antecedent is not universally true.

I've contacted my prior logic course lecturer, and he said something this required higher level of modal logic **(I don't know much about this)** to capture accurately, difference in possibility and necessarily, and then he did not say much more about it.

Appreciate anyone could enlighten me up by first year logic material.

Comment: You have to be careful with concepts, like "universally true" and in comparing statements of mathematics, whose truth value does not change with time ("4 is even" was true, is true and will be true) with everyday's statements like "tomorrow will rain" whose truth value depends on time: the "reference point" is today, but today changes every day.

Comment: Also "logical falsehood" can be misleading; does it mean a statement/formula that is always false, like e.g. "$x$ is not equal to $x$"? If so, $0 \ne 1$ is **not** a "logical" falsehood: it is only a false arithmetical statement.

Comment: $(p \land \lnot q)$ is not a contradiction; with $p$ True and $q$ False, the formula will be True. $(p \land \lnot p)$ is a contradiction.

Comment: "If x is greater than 4, then x is divisible by 2" is sometimes True and sometimes False. What is False is "for every $x$, if $x$is greater than 4, then $x$ is divisible by 2".

Comment: And then we have Modal Logic, the logic of modal operators: it is necessary, it is possible.

Comment: In conclusion: "Logical falsehood entails everything as long as antecedent is not universally true" is not correct. A "logical falsehood", i.e. a contradiction [like e.g. $(p \land \lnot p)$] entails everything because it is **never** true. Thus, a correct example will be: "2 is even and not-even, entails 2=1".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding your third reply,  $(p\land\neg q)$ is not a contradiciton, I totally agree. What I meant was $(p\implies q)\equiv ((q\land \neg q)\implies \bot)$, and when one argues **$7$ is not divisible by 2** means $(p\land \neg q)$, but I don't see a contradiction.  $\dots\dots\dots$ I think I get it now, if $(p\land \neg q)\implies \bot$, then $(p\implies q)$ is true, however it is not. So that such statement is proving $\neg (p\implies q)\equiv (p\land \neg q)$ is true.

Comment: Regarding your second reply, I think $0\neq1$ is true statement, and $x$ is not equal to $x$ is logical a falsehood.

Comment: Sorry for the typo... please read "$0=1$".

Comment: all good now. Does logical falsehood has to be a contradiction? Regarding your first reply, that's my question, what if the antecedent is contingent. How should I verify the statement? If the antecedent **could be False**, is that a logical falsehood?

Comment: **IF** logical falsehood means *contradiction*, then a contingent (sometimes true, sometimes false) statement is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is right is that the (halfway symbolic) proposition

> (1) $X$ is greater than $4$ $\implies$ $X$ is divisible by $2$.

is sometimes true (which is the case, for example, when $X=3$ or $X=8$) and sometimes false (such as when $X=7$). It doesn't *have* a definite truth value until we decide what $X$ is.

$\Rightarrow$ doesn't care whether truths are universal, contingent, necessary, or impossible. It simply asks, "true or false?" of both antecedent and consequent and consults its truth table. If the truth value of the antecedent or consequent varies by context, then so does (potentially) the truth value of the $\Rightarrow$.

The invisible snag in your question is whether the above proposition is the same as

> (2) If $X$ is greater than $4$, then $X$ is divisible by $2$.

Some introdutory textbooks in logic try hard to tell you that (1) and (2) mean exactly the same. Often they even say that the $\implies$ symbol is *defined* by the words "if" and "then", and then separately attempt to convince you that "if"/"then" inherently have the somewhat unusual meaning that you're trying to grasp here.

Really, though, it is a lie-to-children, and not a particularly useful one at that. The *actual meaning people are trying to express* when they say (2) -- even when those people are mathematicians talking about mathematics -- is not unambiguously (1). Very often it is instead something we could formalize as

> (3) $\forall X$[ $X$ is greater than $4$ $\implies$ $X$ is divisible by $2$ ].

which is definitely false because the inner sentence (identical to (1), by the way) is *sometimes* false.

The trouble logic textbooks face is that they often introduce the quantifier $\forall X$ much *later* than they're explaining the "propositional" symbols $\land$, $\lor$, and $\Rightarrow$. During the part of the book where they can't mention $\forall X$, they're reduced to claiming that the English words "and", "or", "if"/"then" mean the same as $\land$, $\lor$, $\Rightarrow$, producing a horribly artificial and mutilated approximation to the meaning of natural language.

A further trouble is that there are no *simple* rules for when we need to insert a $\forall X$ or $\exists X$ in the logical translation of an English sentence. However, that's because the *meaning of English* (like most other natural languages) is fuzzy, highly context-sensitive, and sometimes downright ambiguous -- but not because the *logical formalism* is complicated.

Many students who go with the book's flow unfortunately leave with the opposite impression -- that it's the mathematical formalism that is complex, unpredictable and only accessible by special geniuses.

As long as you stick to propositions like (1) or (3), everything is simple and easy. If you're a native or reasonably fluent speaker of English, you will also be able to deal with (2), *as long as* you accept that you need to figure out from the context whether the speaker meant (1) or (3), or perhaps something subtly different from either of those. It is *not* determined strictly by the words in the sentence itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Logical falsehood entails everything as long as antecedent is not
> universally true?

The basic principle of vacuous truth is given by the tautology $A \implies [\neg A \implies B]$.

Here is the truth table:

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

Here is a formal proof using a simplified form of natural deduction:

(Screen print from my proof checker)

[image]

Note that if the antecedent of any conditional is false (something that usually only comes up in technical proofs) then we cannot infer anything about the consequent. So, it's not, as some would have it, that anything goes in mathematics or logic.

> Example 1: If 4 is an even number, then there is an infinite number of integers.

[image]

> Example 2: If tomorrow (it is) rain heavily, then the streets will be empty.

Classical propositional logic can only be applied in real-world scenarios for propositions that are unambiguously either true or false at some instant in time,  usually the present. The truth value of predictions about the future are always ambiguous.

> Example 3: If X is greater than 4, then X is divisible by 2.

This is contingent on the value of X, thus the truth value of the antecedent and consequent are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

> **example 1** If $4$ is an even number, then there is an infinite number of integers.
>
> $4$ is an even number, universally true; there is an infinite number of integers, universally true; therefore this statement is True.
>
> What if antecedent and consequent are contingent. How should I verify the statement T or F

Then the conditional's truth value (by which we mean truth value in a particular context) depends on its antecedent's and consequent's combination of truth values in that interpretation. You did just this in the above analysis, and determined that the above conditional is *mathematically* true.

This conditional is *logically* contingent though.

> **example 2** If tomorrow rain heavily, then the streets will be empty.
>
> When I have not learned logic, I would say this is false.

This conditional is again *not a tautology*, since it is alternately true and false.

> But now, I may say "well, tomorrow may not be raining", logical falsehood entails everything.

Yes, so in this context/scenario, the conditional is true.

BTW, "tomorrow is not raining" is not a *logical* falsehood: it is true in some universe.

> **example 3** If $X$ is greater than $4$, then $X$ is divisible by $2$. (False, e.g. $7$)

If we are discussing $\mathbb R,$ then this conditional is not universally true; that is, $$\forall X\;(X{>}4\to2|X)\tag1$$ is ***false***; so, it is invalid, so it is not logically true.

> I could also argue that X is not always greater than 4, logical falsehood entails everything.

In fact, let's change the universe of discourse from $\mathbb R$ to $(-\infty,4],$ so that $x$ is now always not greater than $4.$ In this interpretation/context, $(1)$ becomes vacuously ***true***.

But while $x{>}4$ is false in this context, it is true in another context, so is *not* logically false.

> What is the contradiction in this example, and how should I convinced myself do not use logical falsehood entails everything for verifying conditional statement when antecedent is not universally true.

There is no logical falsehood and no contradiction: the antecedent is not universally false in the first interpretation, and universally false in the second interpretation.